# Modify the rc.local of another linux-based OS safely

Tags: linux, boot, permissions, raspberry-pi, file-permissions

I need to modify the `rc.local` of my raspberry OS. If I insert the SD card in my Linux workstation, it says  that

"Geany tried to access the Unix Domain socket of another instance running as another user. This is a fatal error and Geany will now quit."

I don't want to change file permission and/or the ownership of the file because I am afraid to mess up the startup of my raspberry. Any suggestion on how to modify it safely?

Answer (score 1):

This is bizar: Geany is, as far as I know, a text editor. It should not react to USB-cards that are inserted.

What you would normally do:

- open a terminal
- `ls /dev/sd*`
- insert the sd-card
- `ls /dev/sd*`

The difference in the output of the two `ls` outputs will give you the name of the sd-card.

- `mount`

If you have a linux distribution that automatically mounts sd-cards (you probably have), you will see the /dev/sd.. for your sd-d card mounted somewhere.

- `cd` to the directory (probably the /dev/sd.2-mountpoint) and then `cd etc`
- `nano rc.local` or, if you're courageous, `vi rc.local` and edit `rc.local`to your needs
- `cd /`
- unmount all the partitions on the sd-card (`umount /dev/sd.2` etc.)

(if you overestimated your abilities and started `vi`, hit escape and type `:q!` followed by enter)

Comment: "if you are courageous" :) thank you +1